# Aligning toolbar items to the right in Mac app

Tags: macos, toolbar

I was wondering how one would align the items in the toolbar to the right of the interface instead of the default alignment of the left.

[image: I would like to align the 'Item' button to the right]

Answer (score 0):

Add a flexible spacer item left of your button to push it to the right side.